# how to edit? infinite recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

i'm making infinite recycleview with json.
this code works only half
i can see items loaded at first time.
but when i scroll down,
nothing happen,
i guess, maybe onLoadMore() is not working.
i been edited 4hours
direct me
where should i edit?
thank you for interest in this.

MainActivity

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
    private AdapterFish mAdapter;
    protected Handler handler;
    List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Make call to AsyncTask
        new AsyncLogin().execute();


        handler = new Handler();

        mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
        mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data, mRVFishPrice);
        mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new     LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new AdapterFish.OnLoadMoreListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {

                //add progress item
                data.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(data.size() - 1);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        new AsyncLogin().execute();

                    }

                }, 2000);

                System.out.println("load");
            }

        });

    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/test/example.json");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
                    fishData.fishImage= json_data.getString("fish_img");
                    fishData.fishName= json_data.getString("fish_name");
                    fishData.catName= json_data.getString("cat_name");
                    fishData.sizeName= json_data.getString("size_name");
                    fishData.price= json_data.getInt("price");
                    data.add(fishData);
                }

                   // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                    mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                    mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data, mRVFishPrice);
                    mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

AdapterFish.java

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    final private Context context2 = context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataFish> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataFish current;
    int currentPos=0;



    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;


    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 2;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;



    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataFish> data, RecyclerView recyclerView){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        // End has been reached
                        // Do something
                        if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {

                            onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        loading = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return data.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }


    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        MyViewHolder holder;

        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fish, parent, false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        }
        else
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);

            return vh;
        }

    return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        MyViewHolder myHolder= (MyViewHolder) holder;
        DataFish current=data.get(position);
        myHolder.textFishName.setText(current.fishName);
        myHolder.textSize.setText("Size: " + current.sizeName);
        myHolder.textType.setText("Category: " + current.catName);
        myHolder.textPrice.setText("Rs. " + current.price + "\\Kg");
        myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

        // load image into imageview using glide
        Glide.with(context).load("http://192.168.1.7/test/images/" + current.fishImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .into(myHolder.ivFish);

    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
        void onLoadMore();
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        }
    }


        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textFishName;
        ImageView ivFish;
        TextView textSize;
        TextView textType;
        TextView textPrice;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textFishName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFishName);
            ivFish= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFish);
            textSize = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSize);
            textType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textType);
            textPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give my own method of loading more items. You have to create your own abstract class called ScrollRecycler which extends from RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.Here it is implemantation

```
public abstract class ScrollRecycler extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
int page = 0;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
int startingPageIndex = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

public ScrollRecycler(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
    this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
}

public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
    int maxSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
        else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
    }
    return maxSize;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
    int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
    int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

    if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
        int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
        // get maximum element within the list
        lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
    } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
        lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }
    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        page = startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) {
            this.loading = true;
        }
    }
    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
    }
    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
    int visibleThreshold = 10;
    if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
        page++;
        onLoadMore(page);
        loading = true;
    }
}
public abstract void onLoadMore(final int page);
```

And you have to add your abstract class to your RecyclerView not Adapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
private AdapterFish mAdapter;
protected Handler handler;
List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncLogin().execute();


    handler = new Handler();

    mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
    mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data, mRVFishPrice);
    mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mRVFishPrice.addOnScrollListener(new ScrollRecycler(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this)) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page) {
            // you can make network call to Server in order to retrive data here page is comminh
        }
    });


}
```

I think it will help you

Comment: @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page) {
                // you can make network call to Server in order to retrive data here page is comminh
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

Comment: Sardor Islomov i attached like this. Toast isn't working. when i scroll down to bottom. what would be problem? =( could you help me.

Comment: There is problem with Toast I think you have to use MainActivity.this instead getApplication()

Comment: Sardor Islomov. ScrollRecycler class i attached to MainActivity.
and changed Toast to MainActivity.this. then app loading is stoping.
:( help me please. sorry.

Comment: You implement abstract class to your mainActivity yes ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_fragment_all);
    type = getArguments().getString("type");
    if(type.equals(Utils.TYPE_JOURNAL)){
        fab.show();
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                makeSubscribeForJournal();
            }
        });
    }else{
        fab.hide();
    }
    category_name = getArguments().getString("category_name");
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    adapter = new AllAdapter(getContext(), onArticleClickListener);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    swipe.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipe.setRefreshing(true);
            makeCall(1, category_name,type);
        }
    });
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new ScrollRecycler(manager, type) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page) {
            makeCall(page, category_name,type);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Here is my ScrollRecycler abstract class which is same as yours.

```
public abstract class ScrollRecycler extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
int page = 1;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
int startingPageIndex = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
String type;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

public ScrollRecycler(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager ,String type) {
    this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    this.type= type;
}

public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
    int maxSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
        else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
    }
    return maxSize;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
    int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
    int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    if(type.equals(Utils.TYPE_JOURNAL)) {
        if (dy > 0) {
            AllFragment.fab.hide();
        } else {
            AllFragment.fab.show();
        }
    }
    if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
        int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
        // get maximum element within the list
        lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
    } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
        lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }
    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        page = startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) {
            this.loading = true;
        }
    }
    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
    }
    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
    int visibleThreshold = 10;
    if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
        page++;
        onLoadMore(page);
        loading = true;
    }
}
public abstract void onLoadMore(final int page);
```

}